# Convergence of the arc length of an orbit

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was looking through this exercise but couldn't really think of a prove for it:

Consider x'=f(x), with f: $\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ continuously differentiable. Let $(p_m)_{m \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $p_m$ is on the periodic orbit $O_m$ of the ODE with the period $w_m > 0$.
Show that the arc length of the orbit converges to zero, if $p_m$ converges to a fixed point(singularity) $q$ of the ODE and if the sequence $(w_m)_{m \in \mathbb N}$ is bounded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$  be  an  upper bound  for the  periods $\omega_{m}$.  Assume  that $\phi_{t}$ is  the  generating  flow  of  the  vector  field $\dot x =f(x)$. Note that the  flow  $\phi_{t}$ is  a $C^{1}$  function , with respect to both variable $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$  and $t\in \mathbb{R}$.  (See Hirsch, Smale:  Linear  algebra, diff. equation  and  dynamical system). Since $q$ is  a  fixed point, then $\phi_{t}(q)=q$ for  all $t$, in particular for  all $t\in [0,2M]$. From continuity of flow we  have a  neighborhood  $U$  of $q$  such that 
$\bar{U}\; \text{is  compact  and }\;\;\forall x\in U,\;\; \forall t\in [0,2M]: \phi_{t}(x) \; \text{belongs to}\;\;  U$. This  shows that all orbits $O_{m}$ belongs to  $U$. Assume  that $N$  is  an  upper  bound  for  $\parallel f(x) \parallel$ when $x\in U$. Then  we  can  show  that the  arc length of each $O_{m}$ is  less than $MN$, since the length is $\int_{0}^{\omega_{m}} \parallel \dot \gamma(t) \parallel dt \leq MN$.